# Putting javascript code in a title tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to have a if else statement to define what title is produced for the website.. as there is 2 different websites.

When i put it within the title tags it just outputs all my script.. how can i get this to take into account the if statements?

btw type is already defined and works within the code just need this part sorting.

my code:

```
<title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        if (type == "first"){
        document.write('1');
        }
        else if (type == "second")
        {
            document.write('2')};


    </script>

    </title>
```

Comment: use `document.title` not `document.write`.

Comment: You are putting the code under <title> tag. It should be under <head> and then use the document.title value to be changed.

Comment: `if (type == "first"){
      jQuery("title").append("1");
}
else if (type == "second"){
      jQuery("<title>").append("2");
};`

Comment: That should work fine if `type` really is defined. It's not best practice, perhaps, but it should be fine. (You might also consider rational indentation and bracing placement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (type == "first"){
  document.title = '1';
}
else if (type == "second")
{
  document.title = '2';
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
<title>Default title here</title>
<script>
var types = ['first', 'second'], type = types[Math.round(Math.random())];    
if (type == "first") {
    document.title = 'foo';
} else if(type == "second") {
    document.title = 'bar';
}

</script>
```

You will need to define the type variable in an appropriate way.
Also, it is generally not advisable to use names like type for a variable, as type is a common property name. It may even be a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: You need something in the `if()`